# Azure Storage - Handling Double Slash in URL

Tags: c#, azure, url-rewriting, azure-storage

I'm in the process of moving my companies collection of files (15TB) to azure blob storage. Unfortunately these files are pulled down by mobile apps which build the final bit of the URL on the devices. It seems on the apple apps that the device adds a "/" before appending the rest of the path e.g it will take the domain we pass down in the request:

Domain Passed in Request: "files.mycompany.com/"
Appended by Apple Devices "/folder/file.jpg"
Appended by Android Devices "folder/file.jpg"

This causes The apple devices to have a double slash in the path ("//"). When these files are coming from our current datastore this is fine as it evaluates "//" to a single "/" but on azure this isn't the case.

Due to this being one devices, we cannot easily update all our apps and expect every user to actually update. So is there something on azure or maybe something I can do with a custom domain which I could rewrite the URL to remove the "//"?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely include the "/" as a legitimate part of the file URL. Hence as long as you upload it with the extra "/" and it will be stored in storage with a name containing "//" - meaning if you then request the object including "//" it will be returned. The problem then is that the Android apps would either need to be updated which I am guessing has the same problem as the Apple apps. One solution to this is to upload the image twice once with single-slash and the other with double-slash - is that a short-term solution until you have updated the Apple app to behave correctly?

Alternatively you could route the Apple apps through some kind of a proxy that you would have to build that would rewrite the URL. IIS has rewriting support which you can read more about here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had thought a rewrite URL or double uploading might be a solution. I think what we are going to do is update our updates with a fix but also use a new URL for thoses new apps. Then once 80%ish of users update to latest app we can update them to point towards azure directly and then update old apps with only bit of traffic towards a rewrite machine